# Stretch navigation background across screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap.

Exactly like the top bar here on Stackoverflow.

I have responsive design. When I add a background color to my top navigation it stretches but there is a little padding on the left and right. I want it to stretch the light grey ALL the way across.

I guess the "container" class has some padding or a margin in it?

Just like the light grey stretches across the top of this page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Or a link to your site where we can see this. Have you debugged in a browser to see where that spacing is coming from? Is it padding from body tag or margin from the navigation, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a Reset on your css

like the one here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/